# How to fetch last row in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-order-by

I would like to fetch the last row record. But, I am getting the maximum value record from the result set. I would like to know how to get the last row record from my result:

[image]

Comment: is your id a varchar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i believe this is due to the id being a varchar field

try the following

```
select *
  from ref_data.dbo.sample_salesperson
 where cast(id as int)= (select max(cast(id as int))
                           from ref_data.dbo.sample_salesperson
                         )
```

Comment: Note that this is _not_ actually the same logic as the OP, which is using `TOP`.  Your version might get duplicates if `ID` could be duplicated.

Comment: @George Joseph: I got an answer now. It works thanks a lot.

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen good point, i replaced the query OP had used in the example he provided with "max" logic

Comment: But good catch on your end +1, you hit the nail on the head.